# Why does ec2 monitoring show 10% cpu and htop 100%?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am confused. I have an EC2 `t2.micro` (I know, micro, but until recently it was ok) instance with 5 Kafka consumers which, according to `htop`, use 100% CPU all the time. It seems to be confirmed by Kafka, which shows that we have lags, so consumers can't keep up.

However, when I look at CloudWatch for this instance's `CPUUtilisation`, I see that it never goes above 10%. It is always right below this value, which makes me think that I am either choosing wrong metrics, or that I should know that there is some kind of a factor that I should use when setting up my CloudWatch alarms...

*Update*

I checked `mpstat -P all` (as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/369479/amazon-ec2-how-to-find-out-detailed-cpu-usage?rq=1#comment485885_369479)), and it seems that now, the effect is opposite to what was reported [10 years ago](https://serverfault.com/questions/400533/why-does-ec2-monitoring-show-100-cpu-and-top-only-20):

```
20:45:07     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
20:45:07     all   10,80    0,00    1,49    0,71    0,00    0,27   66,92    0,00    0,00   19,81
20:45:07       0   10,80    0,00    1,49    0,71    0,00    0,27   66,92    0,00    0,00   19,81
```

So apparently I can use 10% of CPU max, but CloudWatch doesn't show usage of my share, but of entire CPU...

Comment: Well, there is no better way to display this in a single number, is there? If they represented *"burstable"* (less than 100%, when actually used) resources as a fraction of dynamic limits, they would show something misleading in the other, much more relevant (you would not choose that if you wanted consistent performance) case.

Comment: Perhaps, but in that case, how can I see if my server is not running under 100% CPU load?